# Basic AWQL request - CAMPAING_PERFORMANCE split by "date" only

Tags: google-ads-api, awql

I face strange behavior on my Adwords API response, which brakes a logic of our reports.

Here is my AWQL:
`SELECT Date,Ctr FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING 20181206, 20181206`

Response:

`Report Day,CTR
2018-12-06,0.00%
2018-12-06,3.23%`

Why do I get 2 rows of results, it should be only one (same date). I asked only for one date. Same thing with a different range of dates.

It feels to me like Adwords splits the results by CampaignIds.
It is possible to get "total" result, split by `date`?

Answer (score 2):

`CAMPAIGN_PERFOMANCE_REPORT` is segmented by campaign. If you want `Ctr` by date across an account you need to use `ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` instead

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I will check it and will mark the answer as useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see that `Account Performance Report` has a lot of missing metrics. For example: `BounceRate`, `AveragePageviews`, `AverageTimeOnSite` & etc...

I also use a lot of `Keywords Performance Report`. I wonder if it is possible to avoid this "auto split by campaign_id" adword's default logic...

Comment: They only publish the metrics they publish I suppose. A `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` is always segmented by campaign (just as a `ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` is segmented by adgroup, etc). Depending on the metric you could conceivably return ALL results and aggregate (sum of all clicks divided by sum of all impressions for `Ctr` for example) but we can only work with the metrics AdWords publish

Comment: Well, the calculation process it is something that I tried to avoid :D hehe, but as I see there is no other way... Thank you for your help!